# How to add PATH on continuumio/anaconda3 image with dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to install spark with continuumio/anaconda3 image on docker.

Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
RUN apt update && apt install -y openssh-server curl vim
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN curl -O http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/software/apache/spark/spark-2.4.3/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz &&\
tar -zxvf spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz &&\
mv spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7 /usr/local &&\
ln -s /usr/local/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7 /usr/local/spark
ENV PATH "/usr/local/spark/bin:${PATH}" 
RUN sed -i "s/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config &&\
echo "root:mypasswd" | chpasswd && \
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

I build from the dockerfille, spark and sshd works fine.
But path from this command did not work.

```
ENV PATH "/usr/local/spark/bin:${PATH}"
```

```
#spark-shell
-bash: spark-shell: command not found
```

And this command with full path works fine.

```
#/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-shell
```

I tried to add the line to /etc/profile or /etc/profile.d/xxx.sh, but I got a same bad result.

```
RUN echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/user/local/spark/bin" >> the files
```

**This problem caused by ssh access.** Because of this command works fine about env.

```
docker run -it imagename bash
```

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by `path from this command did not work`? What you expect?

Comment: The error happened "-bash: spark-shell: command not found".
Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: `ENV PATH "/user/local/spark/bin:${PATH}"`, `user`? `usr`? typo?

Comment: It is a typo. Sorry, I revised my mistake in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by ssh, which do not read .bashrc and /etc/profile.d/,
so I changed this line

```
ENV PATH "/usr/local/spark/bin:${PATH}"
```

to

```
#add path to .bashrc
RUN echo "PATH=/usr/local/spark/bin:${PATH}" >> ~/.bashrc
#make .bash_profile which read .bashrc when ssh access
RUN echo "if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then  . ~/.bashrc;  fi" >>~/.bash_profile
```

This code works fine.